# Angular: Call HTTP Observable only once and provide returned data as Observable in Service

Tags: angular

Common Task: I want to fetch data via HTTP only once and then make it accessible to my whole app as properties. But of course my app needs to "listen" to the properties, because HTTP is slow. I only want to call HTTP once (1 time) overall in the entire app.

```
@Injectable()
export class EnvService {

  imageTag: String;


  envData: Observable<any>;


  constructor(protected authHttp: AuthHttp) {

    let envSubscription = this.getConfig().subscribe(envConfig => {

      this.imageTag = envConfig.imageTag;

      this.envData = {
          'imageTag' : envConfig.imageTag,
      }

      envSubscription.unsubscribe();
    });

  }


  getData(): Observable<any> {

    return this.envData;

  }

  getConfig(): Observable<any> {

    const requestOptionsArgs: RequestOptionsArgs = {
      url: '/assets/env/env.json',
      method: RequestMethod.Get
    };

    const requestOptions: RequestOptions = new RequestOptions(requestOptionsArgs);
    return this.authHttp.request(new Request(requestOptions)).map(returnedEnvConfig => {

      return {
        imageTag: returnedEnvConfig.json().imageTag,
      };
    });
  }
}
```

> imageTag: any is not assignable to type Observable

Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: is that helpful ?? updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve your goal by simply using the [rxjs share operator](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/multicasting/share.html).

By default, the Observable returned by the HttpClient will do a new call for every subscription. By adding a `pipe(share())`, you can change the behavior and share the response between all the subscribers.

[Here is a stackblitz demonstration](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-49857430) for the two cases. A line is added in the console for every performed http call.

Answer (score 0):

you can just do this , store data in `localstorage` once request get completed , so next time when you call it will return data from `localstorage` without going to server.

```
  getConfig(): Observable<any> {

    if( this.localStorage.get('key'));
      return of(this.localStorage.get('key'));
   else {

    const requestOptionsArgs: RequestOptionsArgs = {
      url: '/assets/env/env.json',
      method: RequestMethod.Get
    };

    const requestOptions: RequestOptions = new RequestOptions(requestOptionsArgs);
    return this.authHttp.request(new Request(requestOptions)).map(returnedEnvConfig => {
      localStorage.setItem("key",returnedEnvConfig.json().imageTag);
      return  returnedEnvConfig.json().imageTag;
    });
  }
 }
```

---

you just do like this

```
return this.authHttp.request(new 
      Request(requestOptions)).map(returnedEnvConfig => 
       returnedEnvConfig.json().imageTag);
```

---

it should be like

```
return this.authHttp.request(new Request(requestOptions));
```

if you want to return overservable , and where you subscribe do the operation which you are currently doing.

Comment: Sorry that is not helping.

Comment: How to connect `envData: Observable<any>;`  and `imageTag` and the subscriber of the service? HTTP should be completely decoupled.

Comment: @nottinhill - if you want to call once only then susggest store data in localstorage after first request done, kind of cache data , thats what i do in my application

Answer (score 0):

Use `publishReplay(1).refCount();` to cache the operation.

```
 getConfig(): Observable<any> {

    const requestOptionsArgs: RequestOptionsArgs = {
      url: '/assets/env/env.json',
      method: RequestMethod.Get
    };

    const requestOptions: RequestOptions = new RequestOptions(requestOptionsArgs);
    return this.authHttp.request(new Request(requestOptions)).map(returnedEnvConfig => {

      return {
        imageTag: returnedEnvConfig.json().imageTag,
      };
    }).publishReplay(1).refCount();
  }
```

Read more: https://blog.angularindepth.com/rxjs-how-to-use-refcount-73a0c6619a4e